# How to solve these three equations?

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations

If α ,β ,γ are three numbers s.t.:

$\ α^ \ $ + $\ β \ $ +  $  γ \ $ = −2

$\ α^2 \ $ + $\ β^2 \ $ +  $  γ^2 \ $ = 6

$\ α^3 \ $ + $\ β^3 \ $ +  $  γ^3 \ $ = −5,

then $\ α^4 \ $ + $\ β^4 \ $ +  $  γ^4 \ $ is equal to ??

I tried out substituting the values of each equation to one other ...but it became very 
complex .. I also remember some crammers rule for this ..using matrices??
Is that the way??

Comment: Hint: [Newton identities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities).

Comment: This is a variation of [that question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/402856/finding-the-fraction-fraca5b5c5d5a6b6c6d6-when-knowing-the).

Comment: This question seem to be similar, too: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27394/three-variable-system-of-simultaneous-equations/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let $A_{n}=a^n+b^n+c^n$. Then we have
$$A_{n+3}=(a+b+c)A_{n+2}-(ab+bc+ac)A_{n+1}+abcA_{n}$$
and
$$2(ab+bc+ac)=(a+b+c)^2-(a^2+b^2+c^2)=4-6=-2$$

$$a^3+b^3+c^3=(a+b+c)^3-3(a+b+c)(ab+bc+ac)+3abc$$
Then we can easily find $abc$.

Comment: Do you have a reference for proof of equality $A_{n+3}=(a+b+c)A_{n+2}-(ab+bc+ac)A_{n+1}+abcA_{n}$?

Comment: multiplication/algebraic simplification I imagine

Comment: @Ethan Yes, But a reference ?

Comment: it is well kown....and very easy prove it

Answer (score 10):

HINT:

$$a^4+b^4+c^4=(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2-2(a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2)$$

Now $$a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2=(ab+bc+ca)^2-2abc(a+b+c)$$

$$2(ab+bc+ca)=(a+b+c)^2-(a^2+b^2+c^2)$$ we can find $ab+bc+ca$ from here

$$a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc$$

$$=(a+b)^3-3ab(a+b)+c^3-3abc$$

$$=(a+b+c)\{(a+b)^2-(a+b)c+c^2\}-3ab(a+b+c)$$

$$=(a+b+c)\{(a+b)^2+c^2-3ab\}$$

$$= (a+b+c)\{(a+b+c)^2-3(ab+bc+ca)\}$$ we can find $abc$ from here

Comment: It's difficult for me to grasp this (bit weak) .Will try this out.

Comment: @joeyrohan, just understand the formulas and put the known values