# Method to solve a system of nonlinear equations

Tags: nonlinear-system

Suppose that I have the following system,
$$
\begin{equation}
    \left\{\begin{array}{lcl}
    a + b + c + d & = & \alpha \\ 
    a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2  & = & \beta \\
    a^3 + b^3 + c^3 + d^3& = & \gamma \\
    a^4 + b^4 + c^4 + d^4& = & \theta
    \end{array}\right.
\end{equation}
$$
in which I know that $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ are positive, $\alpha=1$, $\beta<1$, $\gamma<1$, and $\theta<1$. If I know the values of $\beta$, $\gamma$, and $\theta$, how can I find $a, b, c, d$? Can someone tell me if there is a method to solve this? Which system of equations is this one? Does this have a specific name?

Comment: Dots are not an existing analytical method to define anything, sorry! Is this supposed to be a finite set of equations with finitely many summands, or what? It's your problem, so *you* have to tell us what kind of system of equations this is.

Comment: I reframed the problem. I hope it become more clear.

Comment: I believe that questions equivalent to this have been asked and answered here many times. See, for example, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/402856/finding-the-fraction-fraca5b5c5d5a6b6c6d6-when-knowing-the

Comment: Thanks Gerry! I have found a good hint in this link!!